# Stripe - SubscriptionSchedule with 3DS

Tags: stripe-payments

I am new with Stripe API and I want to create a `Subscription` per month with letting the possibility to enter a discount code if they want to.

For that, I use [Subscription Schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/object) which allows me to create 2 phases inside. The first one would be, for example, the first week for 1€ and then the regular subscription.
Everything works well and I'm able to create the Subscription Schedule:

```
{
 canceled_at: null
 completed_at: null
 created: 1602415626
 current_phase: {end_date: 1602502026, start_date: 1602415626}
 customer: "cus_IAzNj2kr9i1nw8"
 default_settings: {billing_cycle_anchor: "automatic", billing_thresholds: null, 
 collection_method: "charge_automatically", default_payment_method: null, default_source: null, 
 …}
 end_behavior: "release"
 id: "sub_sched_1Hb2hiLShhG4xDx2Fw5Xn3mg"
 livemode: false
 metadata: {user_id: "263175", promo_code: "", sub_id_id: "11"}
 object: "subscription_schedule"
 phases: (2) [{…}, {…}]
 released_at: null
 released_subscription: null
 renewal_interval: null
 status: "active",
 subscription: "sub_IBPWnRqS6gVVlm"
}
```

The only issue I'm facing is how to validate my user's cards with `Subscription Schedule`? When you create a regular `Subscription` you can have access to either `pending_setup_intent` or `last_invoice.payment_intent`, from which you can either ask 3DS or send an error message.

Can you guys tell me how I can achieve that?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to [retrieve the Subscription by its ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/retrieve) to get those, but then you should have access to them.